# Optional on condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to update a table based on another table.

[image]

I want to update table b using table A.  One Id can have multiple serial number in table B. If I want to update all the serial number for a ID then I will pass null in table A, If I want to update only particular serial number then I will pass that serial number. So Serial number is like optional. How to achieve this?

Comment: What's wrong with something like `WHERE SerialNumber = @SerialNumber OR @SerialNumber IS NULL`? You can use that type on logic in an `ON` clause as well.

Comment: your desired output appears to delete the last two rows with ID 3. Is that correct?

Comment: also " If I want to update all the serial number for a ID then I will pass null in table A, "...but in your example , you use NULL for ID 2, but then the output appears not to have been updated - i.e. the data for ID 2 is still the same. What did you really mean? And for ID 1, the input, the existing data and the output are all the same. It's not clear what, if anything, the query is supposed to do. Your requirements are not at all clear IMO.

Comment: Also, what have you tried so far? This is not really a free write-my-code service. We'll help you, but not do all your work for you. But maybe the reason you're not sure what to do is because the rules for what should happen are not sufficiently clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This covers all cases:

```
SELECT B.ID, B.SerialNumber
FROM TableA A
JOIN TableB B ON A.ID=B.ID AND (A.SerialNumber=B.SerialNumber OR A.SerialNumber IS NULL)
```

---

**Demo:**

```
WITH TableA AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
        (1,'AB'),
        (1,'BC'),
        (2,NULL),
        (3,'AB')
    )T(ID,SerialNumber)
), TableB AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
        (1,'AB'),
        (1,'BC'),
        (2,'AB'),
        (2,'BC'),
        (3,'AB'),
        (3,'BC'),
        (3,'DE')
    )T(ID,SerialNumber)
)
SELECT B.ID, B.SerialNumber
FROM TableA A
JOIN TableB B ON A.ID=B.ID AND (A.SerialNumber=B.SerialNumber OR A.SerialNumber IS NULL)
```

**Result**

```
ID          SerialNumber
----------- ------------
1           AB
1           BC
2           AB
2           BC
3           AB
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join both tables :

```
SELECT [A].[ID]
  ,[B].[SerialNumber]
  ,[A].[Values]
FROM [TableA] A
LEFT JOIN [TableB] B ON ([B].[ID] = [A].[ID] AND ([B].[SerialNumber] = [A].[SerialNumber] OR [A].[SerialNumber] IS NULL))
```